# The geocoding_reverse is not work on real device but work on emulator android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, kotlin, reverse-geocoding

This is my code :

```
    val btnbymap = mycustomview.findViewById<Button>(R.id.edit_by_map)


            btnbymap.setOnClickListener {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        requireContext(),
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                    ) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        requireContext(),
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {

                    this.requestPermissions(
                        arrayOf(
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                        ), RequestCode
                    )


                } else {


                    fusedLocationProviderClient =
                        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(vl.context)
                    fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener(requireActivity()) {


                        if (it != null) {



                            val latitude: Double = it.latitude
                            val longitude: Double = it.longitude

                            val geocoder = Geocoder(this.context, Locale.getDefault())

                            try {

                                val address : List<Address> =
                                geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1)
                                val adress1 = address[0].countryName

                                Toast.makeText(this.context, adress1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


                            } catch (e: Exception) {

                                Toast.makeText(
                                    this.context,
                                    "can't handle this",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                )
                                    .show()

                            }


                        } else {


                            Toast.makeText(context, "can't find location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show()

                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }


        return vl

    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        when (requestCode) {
            1 -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            requireContext(),
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                        ) ==
                                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    ) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                return
            }
        }
    }


}
```

I want use geocoder to get address from LatLngn(Coordinates).

when i use this method (geocoding_reverse) the emulator android studio give me back the address (country name ) but in my real device the catch method give back ( can't handle this ) .

why when i use the emulator the try method worked but in the real device goes to catch method .

where of my codes is wrong ?

how can i handle this ?
tnk's in advancde

Comment: well what does the actual error tell you?

Comment: in doesn't give me error . actually not worked well . it must be goes to try method but goes into catch method .

Comment: it goes into the catch block which means there is an error, read what the exception is

Comment: "can't handle this" change to "Exception: " + e.getMessage().

Comment: i have just debug api not release . could be my problem ?

Comment: the error is : grpc faild